# Activiti - DelegateExpression not Resolving

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, activiti

I am trying to integrate the Activiti-BPM Framework into a Java EE Webapplication.
The main goal at the Moment is, to inject an EJB as DelegateExpression into a Servicetask (to handle Database operations).

I read that Activiti does not (yet) work with EJBs, so i annotated the class like this:

```
@Named
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@Dependent
public class DatabaseWriter implements JavaDelegate {...}
```

and try to inject it in multiple ways like this:

```
activiti:delegateExpression="${DatabaseWriter}"
activiti:delegateExpression="DatabaseWriter"
activiti:delegateExpression="$DatabaseWriter"
```

respectivley to check if it is just a Bug or something:

```
activiti:expression="${DatabaseWriter.execute(execution)}"
```

In any case i get exceptions like "could not resolve DatabaseWriter, no bean foudn that implements JavaDelegate with name DatabseWriter ..."

I tested the Class itself - by not using cdi - JPA does nto work, but the class can be instantiated by Activiti and the execute method is executed - so the class code itself is ok.

I also tried injecting the class in a JAX-RS EJB - both with CDI and @EJB - it works. The problem definetly lies with my way of trying to bring it into Activiti.

I also made a Screenshot of the Problem (all code, xml, and a logmessage) for better understanding, if it helps:

http://s29.postimg.org/tmiknudjb/problem.jpg

Thanks for help or tipps!

Regards,
BillDoor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ejb-3-1-175064.html)

> Annotating the boundary (Cart) with the @Named annotation makes the
>   Cart immediately visible for expression language (EL) expressions in
>   JSP and JSF. This @Named annotation takes the simple name of the
>   annotated class, puts the first character in lowercase, and exposes it
>   directly to the JSF pages (or JSP).

Activiti uses same expression language(EL) so my guess is to you try with;

```
activiti:delegateExpression="${databaseWriter}"
```

Also, I nevered use EJB and Activiti so I'm just guessing, but upper example is how it works with Spring.

Hope it helps.

Comment: stupid people with stupid reading skills think you're better than me - thanks it works^^